# Unable to add array elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a shop cart as an exercise, but some how i'm unable to add the price of the selected products together.

JS:

```
var productPrice = document.getElementById("productPrice");

var totalPrice = document.getElementById("totalPrice");

var addAlert = document.getElementById("addAlert");

var arr = [];

function addToCart() { // onclick Event to add and show the price
 arr.push(productPrice.innerHTML);
 function getSum(total, num) {
 return total + num;
}
var tempTotal = arr.reduce(getSum);
totalPrice.innerHTML = tempTotal;

}
```

So if the price is 2000, and adding it multiple times it should output 2000+2000+2000 = 6000, but now it just outputs 200020002000.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Cast to number first. `arr.push(Number(productPrice.textContent))`

Comment: (Don't use `innerHTML` unless you're deliberately inserting or accessing HTML markup - otherwise, use `textContent`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to convert `productPrice.innerHTML` to number.

```
function addToCart() { // onclick Event to add and show the price
  arr.push(Number(productPrice.innerHTML));
  function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }
  var tempTotal = arr.reduce(getSum);
  totalPrice.innerHTML = tempTotal;
}
```

Comment: yeah I intend to , SO wants me to wait for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are appending string value , so you need to convert it into number value and shorted way to do it is

```
//make use of text instead of html 
const number:Number = +productPrice.innerText;
```

so in your code you have to do like this

```
let arr:Number = [];
//define array with number type so you cannot add other then number 
arr.push(+productPrice.innerText);
//addeing number to array
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Tankit88**, you will need to convert string formed numbers in array to number i.e. `'2000' => 2000` using `parseInt()` which is clear in the executed code on **Node REPL** after the below code.

```
var productPrice = document.getElementById("productPrice");
var totalPrice = document.getElementById("totalPrice");
var addAlert = document.getElementById("addAlert");

var arr = [];

function addToCart() { // onclick Event to add and show the price
    arr.push(parseInt(productPrice.innerHTML));

    function getSum(total, num) {
        return total + num;
    }

    var tempTotal = arr.reduce(getSum);
    totalPrice.innerHTML = tempTotal;
}
```

Finally, have a look at the below executed lines on **Node REPL** which clarifies the above code's logic.

```
> arr = ['2000', '2000', '2000']
[ '2000', '2000', '2000' ]
>
> function getSum(total, num) {
...  return total + num;
... }
undefined
>
> var tempTotal = arr.reduce(getSum);
undefined
>
> tempTotal
'200020002000'
>
> // A little change to solve above problem
undefined
> function getSum(total, num) {
...  return parseInt(total) + parseInt(num);
... }
undefined
>
> var tempTotal = arr.reduce(getSum);
undefined
>
> tempTotal
6000
>
```

Thanks.